# Do IIS / ASP.NET / MVC version headers reveal patch presence?

Tags: asp.net, iis, patching, asp.net-mvc

Quick question: does anyone know whether the IIS / ASP.NET / MVC version headers, like this:

```
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 5.2
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
```

can be used to determine whether the server is missing any patches?

If yes, is there a good resource available to map these version identifiers to patch levels?

Answer (score 2):

No, these headers don't say anything about the server itself, only that it's running Windows (Because of the IIS).

The other two headers are the .Net and MVC framework version, which both are respective to the application running in the IIS.

You can find more information about those headers and how to remove them [here](https://www.troyhunt.com/shhh-dont-let-your-response-headers/).

Comment: Thanks! Yeah my issue is that Googling for this I only find references to how to switch off these headers. :) But I'm looking to determine whether there's an actual vulnerability there.

Comment: @MarkKoek Hit it with a vulnerability scanner.. If you're authorized to do so.

Comment: All I get are generic issues about version number disclosure. I suspect vulnerability scanners don't look at this - maybe I should try setting up a server that sends a fake version header and see how vuln scanners respond...